# Inserting name into table and populating another table with the same ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database, gridview

I have an insert button capable of inserting a team name into `Team` along with its incremental `Team_ID`. My intention is to have a GridView populate with the new team using `Team_ID` and `Team_name`. Something similar to this:

[image]

Below is all the code/diagrams for my tables and insert query. Any select statement I've tried does not join the two tables since there is no record created in `LeagueTable` after pressing the button. I want the button to create a record inside `LeagueTable` as well as `Team` using the same ID.

[image]

[image]

```
        protected void NewTeamBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        string qry1 = "INSERT into Team (Team_name) VALUES (@Team_name)";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry1, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(("@Team_name"), SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NewTeamTxtBox.Text;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        Response.Redirect("EnterData.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by your schema; should the LeagueTable really have the TeamID? It seems to me the TeamTable would have LeagueID as a foreign key with LeagueTable (such that every team is in a league and multiple teams can share a league).

Also, does your EnterData page have a way to gather both Team Name and League Name? Otherwise how do you know if you need to create a new League and which League ID to give to the team? Perhaps all of this is mute and each team has it's own league as your schema indicates.

Finally, does the sqlcommand generate an id in your table? Just asking because if you need to insert the Team_ID into the LeagueTable, you'll need some way of generating/fetching that. If you are just inserting a new league for every team name, you could have an additional sqlcommand that simply inserts into LeagueTable instead of Team.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm only intending to use LeagueID as a primary key for that table, I don't intend to have other leagues so I could change that but wouldn't know what for. Right now I am just using EnterData to display `LeagueTable` and testing to see if a name entered into NewTeamBtn populates `LeagueTable` with a record.

I have Team_ID set as IsIdentity so that every new team added by the NewTeamBtn gets a new ID, incremented by 1. For simplicity, I would rather the user not have to enter their own ID for a team and have the command do that for them.

Comment: Just for future reference, you might want to put requests for clarification in a comment rather than an answer (Once you unlock commenting)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @F.StephenQ!

Comment: @A.McLean
If you want to create a League with the same ID as Team, you could add another sql command after you write to Team, with this query:
INSERT INTO LeagueTable (League_ID, Team_ID)
VALUES ((select Team_ID from Team where Team_name = @Team_name), (select Team_ID from Team where Team_name = @Team_name))

This does not check to see if the League already exists, but it sounds like you are handling that another way. Let me know if this is helpful or if I'm missing something. If this works, I'll move this insert statement into the answer and call it good.
Thanks!